# How to pass email verification as link versus plain text

Tags: php, html, ios

I am using the following handlebars template and for some reason is keeps sending the change email link as plain text instead of a clickable URL.

It would be huge if someone could point me in the right direction.

```html
Hello {{name}},
<br/><br/>
You have requested a new password! 
<br/><br/>
To create a new password, please click the following link:
<a href="{{changelink}}" title="Change password">{{changelink}}</a>
<br/><br/>
If you did not request this change, feel free to ignore this email.
<br/><br/>
Thank you for using our services!
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the email has a `Content-type: text/html` header.

Comment: thanks Paul, so instead this: <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
  Hello {{name}},
  <br/><br/>
  You have requested a new password! 
  <br/><br/>
  To create a new password, please click the following link:
  <a href="{{changelink}}" title="Change password">{{changelink}}</a>
  <br/><br/>
  If you did not request this change, feel free to ignore this email.
  <br/><br/>
  Thank you for using our services!
</html>

Comment: No, not a meta tag in the HTML, but a message header.